# Smack say "waiting for establishing TLS" while using no TLS

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am using `Smack library version 4.3.4` to connect to jabber server in `Android`.
I test connectection with server A and B that both installed `ejabberd` with same config.
I can connect to server A but can't connect to server B.

I don't use secure connection and in `ejabberd` I set these config in both servers:

```
tls: false
starttls_required: false
```

Smack forces use `TLS` when connecting to server B and show this error:

`No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). While waiting for establishing TLS`

While connection to server A is OK.

My code is:

```
final XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder confBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
        .setCompressionEnabled(false)
        .setSendPresence(true)
        .setConnectTimeout(10000)
        .setHost(host)
        .setDebuggerFactory(ReflectionDebuggerFactory.INSTANCE)
        .setPort(port)
        .setXmppDomain(host)
        .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
        .setSocketFactory(SocketFactory.getDefault())
        .setResource(DeviceInformation.getDeviceAndroidId());

final XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf = confBuilder.build();

TLSUtils.acceptAllCertificates(confBuilder);
TLSUtils.disableHostnameVerificationForTlsCertificates(confBuilder);

SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("SCRAM-SHA-1");
SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");
```